# Basic form page in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am really new to Node Js and Express Js and i am following the (book)[[http://www.sitepoint.com/store/jump-start-node-js/]](http://www.sitepoint.com/store/jump-start-node-js/%5d) to learn Node Js.

In the book the author created a simple page for simple Login Form. I am following that but getting 404 Not found.

```
Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/app.js:29:15)
at trim_prefix (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:240:15)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
at Function.proto.process_params (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:137:5
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:10
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:14)
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
```

I added the following code in **App.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/form', function(req, res){
fs.readFile('.views/form.html', function(error, content){
    if(error){
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
    }
    else{
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
});
```

});

and then created a file **form.html** in **Views** folder in which i created a simple html form.

This didnt work for me, so following the flow of default **index.jade**, i created a file **form.js** and added the following code in it

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/form', function(req, res) {
res.render('form');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Which also did not work. I am sure i am doing something wrong but i do not know where.

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have those files :

---

-- app.js

-- routes (folder containing root.js)

-- views (folder containing form.jade)

---

Then, in your app.js :

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use('/', require('./routes/root')); // Say that all the routes defined in root.js will start with http://yourdomain.com/
```

And in root.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET http://yourdomain.com/form */
router.get('/form', function(req, res) {
    res.render('form'); // Render form.jade view
});
```

Of course, this is really minimalist and you'll have much more things to do... but I hope this will help you to better understand node.js using Express

[Express Router documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i use simple HTML instead of jade?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) template engine then. It really looks like just simple HTML with some dynamic things

Answer (score 0):

I am new to NodeJS and Express too but I think the problem is that you never declare where to find the form.html file. Right before the app.get('/form',....), put app.use(express.static(__dirname+'put the directory your form.html is in or dont put anything if it's not in a directory')); this way express knows where to find the form.html and you shouldn't get a 404 anymore

Comment: Now it is giving me 
 node www GET /form 500 7ms

Comment: To confirm you have app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/Views"));

and this is purely for testing but remove the content of the get method, so remove the readFile within the get and just type res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end(content, 'utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

Express provides a `sendFile` function in the response object, which allows you to do this:

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('./views/form.html', {root: __dirname}, function(error, content){
      if(error){
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
      }
    });
});
```

The jade renderer isn't used in this case.